# How to check If all elements in a NumPy array are either 0 or 2?

Tags: python, numpy

Pseudocode:

```
if (all elements in c == 0) or (all elements in c == 2):
    # all elements in 'c' are either 0 or 2.
    . . .
```

If `c = numpy.array[0,0,2]` the condition is `true`,
but if `c = numpy.array[0,1,2]` it is `false`.

How to test this condition in Numpy efficiently?

Comment: Ok. my question should be more clear. the array is a numpy array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) is designed for this:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([0, 0, 2])
arr2 = np.array([0, 1, 2])

np.isin(arr1, [0, 2]).all()
# True

np.isin(arr2, [0, 2]).all()
# False
```

This, of course, works regardless of ndim:

```
arr3 = np.random.randint(0, 3, (100, 100))
arr4 = np.random.choice([0,2], (100, 100))

np.isin(arr3, [0, 2]).all()
# False

np.isin(arr4, [0, 2]).all()
# True
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use binary operators as logical ones:

`((x == 0) | (x == 2)).all()`

This is slightly faster (~20-30%) than "np.isin" solution.

Answer (score 4):

Simple method :
Just count the number of 0s and 2s , check if it's count is equal to length of array:

```
def check(array):
   return array.count(0) + array.count(2) == len(array)
```

Comment: This works for Normal arrays, if you are sticking to numpy use the solution provided by @Chris

Answer (score 0):

quick visual test is doing

```
np.unique(arr1)
```

This lists all the unique elements in arr1. So if you get anything that doens't contain only 0 or 2 you can visually know immediately. Just a tip.

Comment: computing unique() requires sorting whole ```arr1```, thus it will be significantly slower than other solutions